# How to recognize an instance of UISwitch in code, when only a single IBAction is set up?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Suppose you have 2 `UISwitch` objects placed onto your storyboard. Each of them can be in either on or off state.

[image]

Further assume `IBAction` is setup to link storyboard with the code:

```
- (IBAction)activityTurnedOn:(UISwitch*) activitySwitch;
```

**Question:**
Is there a way I can identify each of many `UISwitch` objects i use, to know, inside the code, which one was just turned on or off? Is there a property i can assign via Interface Builder, which i can test in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you cannot assign different outlets for these switches.

- (this is not a hack) You can assign "tag" property for each one and check for it in a activityTurnedOn: method.
- (this is a hack) You also can check some strange parameters like y-position of switches.
- (may be it is not possible either) you can create several subclasses of UISwitch and assign different class to switches.

Comment: I like this. How can i do this from the interface builder please?

Comment: Or you can use "switch1.tag = 239; switch2.tag = 240;" in the code. It's a simple integer.

Comment: In order to use `switch1.tag = something`, i need to have separate outlets for each of the switches, right?

Comment: Well, maybe you can distinguish these switches somewhere by another parameter? Setup them there.

Comment: But, generally yes, you'll need outlets

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set the objects tag in interface builder, then you can retrieve this in code: `if (activitySwitch.tag == 1) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You have each switch as an outlet, then check if `activitySwitch ==` your outlet variable. I find this makes for more readable code than using tags, and you usually end up wanting to change the state of the switch from somewhere else anyway, so you end up needing the outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign in your .h file 2 IBOutlets, like this:

```
IBOutlet UISwitch *firstSwitch;
IBOutlet UISwitch *secondSwitch;
```

and in your method do this :

```
- (IBAction)activityTurnedOn:(UISwitch*) activitySwitch {
if (activitySwitch == firstSwitch) {

} else if (activitySwicth == secondSwitch) {

 }
}
```

Or you can assign tags to your switches in your nib file (since they are derived from UIView) and do:

```
- (IBAction)activityTurnedOn:(UISwitch*) activitySwitch {
if (activitySwitch.tag == yourFirstSwitchTag) {

} else if (activitySwicth.tag == yourSecondSwitchTag) {

 }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to use separate `IBOultet` for each object.

Comment: I haven't finished writing my answer. Check it now.